# python3 problema al usar librería pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

pues bien, resulta que he instalado desde el terminal con pip la librería pygame para conocer cómo hacer juegos en python, cuando pruebo ejecutar algún código de ejercício a los pocos segundos aparece el error (no responde) y debo cerrar la ventana de pygame.
tambien he probado escribiendo dos códigos completos antes de ejecutarlos y en ambos casos la pantalla del monitor se pone negra y luego se apaga la pc por completo.
de momento no he encontrado data de ése tipo de error ni en el sitio de pygame ni en python.

[image: aquí la captura del error :]

y aquí parte del código que dá el error :

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
width =600
height =300
white = (255 , 255 , 255)
black = (0 , 0 , 0)
red = (255 , 0 , 0)

window = pygame.display.set_mode ((width , height))
playing = True

while playing :
    window.fill (red)

pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Publica un código (corto) que muestre el problema que mencionas. Edita tu pregunta e incluye el código como texto.

Comment: ok, editado compañero. espero esté mas claro así.

Comment: el que se apague la pc no lo sé, nunca me pasó, pero partamos de la base que a ese código le falla la indentación de la última línea, debe estar a la misma altura que la anterior.

Answer (score 0):

haciendo pruebas en bruto, como el código está muy incompleto, le agregué un par de cosas, así lo probás y ves si sigue dando error:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *       #siempre es mejor importar todo


pygame.init()
width =600
height =300
white = (255 , 255 , 255)
black = (0 , 0 , 0)
red = (255 , 0 , 0)

window = pygame.display.set_mode ((width , height))
playing = True

while playing :
    window.fill (red)
    for evento in pygame.event.get():            #lee los eventos del teclado
            if evento.type == QUIT:                  #si cierro
                pygame.quit()                        #cierro los modulos  
                sys.exit()           
    pygame.display.update()
```

me parece que es mejor poner esas líneas, porque sino pygame se queda como esperando

Comment: gracias, escribí tu código. se quitó el error de (no responde) el pc se apaga de todas formas, asi que se me ocurrió analizar la temp. de la gpu mientras ejecúto el código y encontré que dícha temp. se eleva muchísimo. igual mi gpu anda necesitando un cambio de pasta térmica.